# add white space when create a div when prepend

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use this

```
$("#containerSeparateChart").prepend("<div class="+ key +"></div>")
```

to create dynamic  `div` when I click a button depend on the key I create the name of the class, but now I want to add one more class for example `col-xs-6`

I try this

```
$("#containerSeparateChart").prepend("<div class="+ key +"col-xs-6"+"></div>")
```

this add the class but, together like this `class="keynamecol-xs-6"` and I want a space between the name  like this `class="keyname col-xs-6"`

I try to use all this option

- `$("#containerSeparateChart").prepend("<div class="+ key +" col-xs-6"+"></div>")`
- `$("#containerSeparateChart").prepend("<div class="+ key +"&nbsp;col-xs-6"+"></div>")`
- `$("#containerSeparateChart").prepend("<div class="+ key + " "+"col-xs-6"+"></div>")`

But all this case create something like this

```
class="keyname" "col-xs-6"
```

Any idea what I doing wrong!

thanks in advance!

Comment: Try this: $("#containerSeparateChart").prepend("<div class='"+ key +" col-xs-6'></div>")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a small issue with your quotes:

```
$("#containerSeparateChart").prepend('<div class="' + key + ' col-xs-6"></div>');
```

**Example:** https://jsfiddle.net/qv49p1az/1/

---

*Side note:* If you are not already, I would recommend using a code editor (IDE) such as Atom (http://atom.io). Most modern editors would typically pick up on syntax errors like this.

Answer (score 2):

**jQuery:**

```
var child = $('<div>').addClass(key + ' col-xs-6')
$("#containerSeparateChart").prepend(child)
```

**Without jQuery:**

```
var child = document.createElement('div');
child.classList.add(key)
child.classList.add('col-xs-6');

document.querySelector("#containerSeparateChart").appendChild(child)
```

**es6 jQuery:**

```
$("#containerSeparateChart").prepend(`<div class="${key} col-xs-6"></div>`)
```

Comment: you're missing the `key` bit

Comment: @Ted added, also version without jQuery

Comment: I just don't see the jQuery solution as a good one - 3 function calls (1 prepend and 2 addClass) but can be done easily with 1 prepend or 1 prepend and 1 addClass

Comment: @TheOneandOnlyChemistryBlob yes, I agree, its not the optimal, it requires 3 function calls. I just wanted to show that you dont need string concatenation. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
$("#containerSeparateChart").prepend('<div class="' + key + ' col-xs-6"></div>');
```

You need to alternate your quotes to properly concatenate the variable `key`. No need to use a non-breaking space for separation of classes - a simple white space will do.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#containerSeparateChart").prepend('<div class="' + key + ' col-xs-6"></div>')
```

ES2015:

```
$("#containerSeparateChart").prepend(`<div class="${key} col-xs-6"></div>`)
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

```
$("#containerSeparateChart").prepend("<div class="+ key +"></div>");
$('.' + key).addClass('col-xs-6');
```

Comment: Yes @Sankar Raj I try but this case put the class in a father  in  containerSeparateChart

Comment: @Stone No. did you tried? check out this... https://jsfiddle.net/sank8893/x4p9ykx8/

Answer (score 0):

your 1st approach was correct but you had errors in your quotes

```
$("#containerSeparateChart").prepend("<div class='"+ key +" col-xs-6"+"'></div>")
```